# I don't want browser to cache response redirect

Tags: c#, asp.net, caching, redirect, response.redirect

When an error occures i am doing Response.Redirect

but i see that this is causing some visitors trouble. Because stupid browser uses cache and they are not able to see that page again. Since error was temporary, it is causing huge trouble

So i don't want any of this redirects to be cached

I did a little search and come up with

```
Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.ServerAndNoCache)
```

But i want everything to be cached (images) expect redirect itself. So what is the best solution ?

Asp.net c# 4.5 - netframework 4.5

Comment: See if you can change the http-status-code to 302 or 307 (temperary-redirect) the browsers wont cache it then.

Comment: @CorvinMcpherson it was default behaviour to not cache. Actually currently they are supposed to not cache the response.redirect. But some visitors are reporting that they keep getting redirected. So it seems like their browsers are caching even though default they should not cache.

Comment: Side note: "some people report some trouble" is hard to fix. Reproduce the behavior yourself or collect more information till you can understand the problem. For all you know they set the browser to never invalidate the cache... Consider asking for Fiddler trace (or other tool that will report all request browser makes) to make sure you understand what is and what is not cached.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov you are very right. i am capturing server side errors. But there is no error. Definitely caused by user browser. And i am not able to reproduce error. But i am pretty sure it is caused by the cache.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One simple trick is to add a random parameter to the end of your redirect url.

For example

```
Response.Redirect("/page.aspx?_rnd=" + RndNumber);
```

Where `RndNumber` is a random number, and you create the url by checking if have other parameters or not, to properly add the random one. Browsers cache the page url together with the url parameter,  so you avoid the issue you mention.

Comment: now this is a nice solution. but as far as i tested, the Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.ServerAndNoCache) method does not force browser to reload images or javascript or css files. am i incorrect ?

Comment: @MonsterMMORPG You are correct. Each file have their personal headers for the cache.

Comment: you can apply the same pattern to static files as well.. you probably want to base this "cache buster" on something other than a random number though to have more control over when you want the clients to get new files

Comment: @Aristos so there is no harm of putting no cache to aspx files :) good to know. since browser will still cache everything (images,css,javascript files)